# Adding decimal point and zeroes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

Is there a way to specify that a `double` datatype will always have 2 points after the decimal point like currency usually has (oracle db) ?

that is:

```
100 will be converted to 100.00
101.1 will be converted to 101.10
```

Tried casting it and setting precision-scale but no luck with that it doesnt add default decimal point and zeroes

```
SELECT CAST((600.2) AS NUMERIC(28,2)) FROM DUAL;
```

Gives me `600.2`

Comment: Store them as numbers and use `to_char()` function to format the output. `to_char(num_col, 'fm990D00')`. Change format sting so it meets the length of a number. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/4474)

Comment: You should not use an approximate floating point datatype such as `double` (which is `BINARY_DOUBLE` in Oracle). Use a precise type instead, such as `NUMBER(10,2)`. As to decimal places shown, you got your answer already; 100 = 100.0 = 100.00 = 100.000 etc., i.e. the number stored is always the same. If you want a certain representation then use `to_char` to show the number in a string of the desired format.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT to_char(101, '999.90') FROM DUAL;
SELECT to_char(101.1, '999.90') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just formatting the output in your client.

For example, in SQL*Plus set **numformat**:

```
SQL> set numformat 999.99
SQL> SELECT CAST((600.2) AS NUMERIC(28,2)) FROM DUAL;

CAST((600.2)ASNUMERIC(28,2))
----------------------------
                      600.20
```

You could also use **TO_CHAR**, but use it only to display, for any number arithmetic you should leave the number as it is.

```
SQL> select to_char(600.2, '000.00') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
 600.20
```